# access vagrant VM from different operating system

Tags: unix, vagrant, virtualbox

I have set up vagrant VM in a Dropbox folder (at Linux)

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
```

Now I want to access it from OS X:

```
$ vagrant up
```

> The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
>   current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
>   be used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
>   that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.
>
> The UID used to create the VM was: 1000 Your UID is: 501

Does it mean **NO** officially?

This VM is provided by VirtualBox and I have it installed on both machine.

How do I access it from different operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The vagrant machine was created with a user with uid 1000, but the user trying to login to the machine has an uid of 501.

**Reason:**
The uid of the user's from Linux and OS X are different. As, vagrant find the uid to be different, the above error is thrown.

**Explanation:**
The uid of Linux user is 1000 and the uid of OSX user is 501.

So, if a vagrant box is created from Linux, the uid for the vagrant box is marked as 1000. After rebooting to OSX, when you try to start the instance, vagrant identifies a different uid (501 from OSX), because of which vagrant denies access to the machine.

**Solution:**
Edit the file `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid` and change 1000 to 501. Reload vagrant machine and ssh into the machine. The .vagrant folder is in the same folder as Vagrantfile.